# C++ "else" statement when the preceding line has multiple "if" statements

Tags: c++, if-statement, standards, undefined-behavior

The following C++ program

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
        if(i==1) if(j==2) std::cout << "A " << i << ' ' << j << std::endl;
        else std::cout << "B " << i << ' ' << j << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
B 1 0
B 1 1
A 1 2
B 1 3
B 1 4
```

From this I infer that the "else" statement is referring to the second "if".

Is this behavior described in the C++ standard? Is there a reason for implementing it this way? I intuitively expected "else" to refer to the first "if".

Comment: A good example of why you should use braces and indenting.

Comment: It refers to the nearest preceding `if` in the same scope. It wouldn't be much use if it didn't.

Comment: "Is there a reason for implementing it this way?" how else would it work? If you add the braces you will see that if the else would refer to the first `if` there would be no way to use an `else` for the second

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I assumed that if the "if" statement is contained in one line then the right brace will be at the of that line

Comment: @jtalk You assumed it why? Where in the language specification is that stated?

Comment: lines dont matter. You can put everything in one line or every token on a seperate line without changing the meaning

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was an answer that tried to advocate adding braces. We can rearrange your code also without braces to see more clearly what it does (and why it is not doing what you intended):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
        if(i==1) 
            if(j==2) 
                std::cout << "A " << i << ' ' << j << std::endl;
            else 
                std::cout << "B " << i << ' ' << j << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The general syntax (see eg [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)) is:

```
if ( condition ) statement-true
```

In your case the whole

```
            if(j==2) 
                std::cout << "A " << i << ' ' << j << std::endl; // [1]
            else 
                std::cout << "B " << i << ' ' << j << std::endl; // [2]
```

is the `statement-true`. While general `if-else` is:

```
if ( condition ) statement-true else statement-false
```

Hence, `[1]` is the `statement-true` and `[2]` is the `statement-false` of the inner if-else-statement.

Intendation and lines do not matter, thats why it is advisable to always use braces:

```
        if(i==1) {
            if(j==2) { 
                std::cout << "A " << i << ' ' << j << std::endl;
            } else {
                std::cout << "B " << i << ' ' << j << std::endl;
            }
        }
```

Or, if thats what you want:

```
        if(i==1) {
            if(j==2) { 
                std::cout << "A " << i << ' ' << j << std::endl;
            }
        } else {
            std::cout << "B " << i << ' ' << j << std::endl;
        }
```

Credits goes to acraig5075, this is basically just a reformulation of their (now deleted) answer.

Comment: fwiw, same critique applied to acraigs answer can be applied here, not sure how deep one has to go. I know that this isnt as good as accurately quoting the standard, but I hope it is enough to convince

Comment: more specifically, the weak point is "In your case the whole ... is the `statement-true`" not sure how to make that more clear